# Struggling to prove that a function is continuous in some places and discontinuous in others. [Potentially Resolved]

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is what I'm trying to prove:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be represented by 
>   $$
>   f(x) =
>   \begin{cases}
>   1/q & \text{if $x=p/q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q>0$, and $|p|$ and $q$ relatively prime} \\
>   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
>   \end{cases}
> $$
>   $f(x)$ is discontinuous for rational numbers and continuous for irrational numbers.

This is the definition of continuous I am trying to use.

> A function is said to be continuous at a point $x_0$ if all sequences $\{x_n\}$ which converge to $x_0$ cause the image sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ to converge to $f(x_0)$. A function is continuous if it is continuous at every point in its domain.

### Proof for Irrationals

Let $x_0$ be irrational.

Then $x_0$ cannot be represented as a ratio of integers, so $f(x_0)=0$.

By the sequential compactness of the rationals and irrationals, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{u_n\}$ and a sequence of irrational numbers $\{v_n\}$ which both converge to $x_0$.

Note, however, that for an infinite sum of irrational numbers to converge to an irrational number, $p_n$ and $q_n$ cannot converge, otherwise $x_0$ could be represented as a ratio. Therefore $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/q_n = 0$$

Therefore $$\{f(u_n)\}\rightarrow 0$$ And because $\{v_n\}$ is a sequence of irrational numbers, $$\{f(v_n)\}\rightarrow 0$$

Therefore $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

### Proof for Rationals

Suppose that $x_0$ is rational.

Then $x_0=p/q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q>0$, and $|p|$ and $q$ relatively prime.

By the sequential compactness of the rationals and irrationals, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{u_n\}$ and a sequence of irrational numbers $\{v_n\}$ which both converge to $x_0$.

Because $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence of rational numbers converging to a rational number, $$\{f(u_n)\}\rightarrow 1/q$$

Since $\{v_n\}$ is a sequence of irrational numbers converging to a rational number, $$\{f(u_n)\}\rightarrow 0$$

Therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.

Comment: “Converge to $1/q$”: what does that mean? Aren’t the $1/q$’s near to $x_0$ suitably small?

Comment: @MurderOfCrows Related: Wikipedia's [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) article. Also, shouldn't your second section title be "Proof for Rationals" instead of repeating "Proof for Irrationals"?

Comment: @Lubin That is a great point - I used it to complete the proof.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I corrected the section titles, as well as their contents. I cannot use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity, but I can use sequential compactness and the definition I gave above. I think I was able to make it work.